# Xamarin await PushAsync behavior

Tags: c#, xamarin, async-await, navigation

Lets say I have this code:

```
try
{
   await ((MasterDetailPage)Application.Current.MainPage).
      Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(new SecondPage());
}
finally
{
   Console.WriteLine("Completed");
}
```

When "Completed" is outputted, has SecondPage only been  pushed to navigation stack or it had been pushed and its content has been loaded also? In other words, "await PushAsync" awaits entire page be loaded or waits only the pushing?

Comment: Set a breakpoint at the WriteLine and run the app in debug mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a simple test to find out the order:

In the MianPage:

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new Page1());
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Completed");
    }
}
```

In the Page1:

```
public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
{
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Console.WriteLine("Page1" + "Construction");
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        Console.WriteLine("Page1" + "OnAppearing");
    }
}
```

And the result is:

[image]

So, when `Completed` is outputted, the page is `visible` in your app and you can load data in the `OnAppearing` or `Construction` method.